# What is the speck moving in the sky in the very last scene of My Little Pony: FIM S6 E2?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

In the newest episode of *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic*, S6 E2 “The Crystalling, part 2”, at the very last scene before the end credits start, there's a small moving speck visible in the sky.  What is that speck?  Is it a pegasus, a changeling, a griffon, a cloud, a bird, a plane?

Here's an animation showing only that speck in the sky cropped.  (Update: I have replaced the previous animation with a higher resolution one.)  The camera is slanted in this scene, so the speck is actually flying horizontally.

[image: (Cropped stationary image of speck on the sky)]     [image: (Cropped animation of speck on the sky)]

And here's a full screenshot, showing the train that the main cast is taking home from the Crystal Empire.  Follow the image to get [a full resolution screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zi6u.jpg).

[image: (Frame showing speck in the sky)]

Comment: And here I was, wondering how long it would take @b_jonas to notice it. I bet it is yet another cliffhanger for an episode yet to come. The shape, is quite interesting.... it moves without evident flapping or anything. It almost ressemble one of those "Pinkuis Pieicus's Flying Something" .

Comment: (maybe it was Discord, angry for not receiving any invite when even the newcomer got one)

Comment: The high resolution full quality release of the episode is now available. I should examine it and add better screenshots here.

Comment: Considering Ajedi32's answer that seems rather definitive, plus the fact that it is unknown if skylarks even exist in MLP:FIM, would you consider reevaluating your check-mark?

Comment: @Ellesedil: I was sort of hoping Rand would re-evaluate his answer knowing that the camera in this scene was tilted, which he missed at first.  I don't think either is definitive though.

Comment: @b_jonas I think that "I was right, that was a character from a future episode" answer I posted it is as far as an official source-based answer you will get for the time begin. Unless that is also a red herring to make you think he was the only one there at that time :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only somehow-canon answer we can get comes from a successive episode.

In episode 16 of the same season Twilight, Spike and Starlight discover that there have been recent sightseeing of a changeling near the Crystal Empire - and the Crystal ponies are pretty scarred because of this. Later in the same episode, Spike will meet this same changeling named **Thorax**, who will then explain that he left his people and have been recently drawn to the Crystal Empire by the great concentration of love that seem to forming there - probably because of the Crystalling.

For these reason, even if the episode **doesn't state directly** that it was Thorax flying over the city in that last scene, I would argue that probably that is the most appropriate explanation. **The whole scene would then be a little Easter egg clue to a future episode**, much like they had back in season 5 where Starlight could be spotted spying on Twilight during some episodes.

Answer (score 14):

It's a [changeling](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Changelings):

[image: Zoom! Enhance!]

Changelings in a previous episode for comparison:

[image: Changelings in A Canterlot Wedding]

Comment: That's some [CSI bullsh*t right there](http://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/2078832_700b.jpg). Well done. :-)

Comment: Actually, the fun part is that there have been rumor of a future Chrysalis&Flurry Heart episode, so having a changeling there would be a great touch :P

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: There was an episode I watched recently on Netflix that had a young Changeling sitting with a group of foals in a fairly peaceful manner. I don't remember which episode it was, but I think it was from season 5.

Comment: @Ellesedil S5E9, Slice of Life. That one's name is "Kevin".

Comment: @Ajedi32: That's the one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Disclaimer: I know nothing about the *My Little Pony* franchise, but I do know a lot about birds.</sup>

The flight pattern instantly made me think of the **skylark** (*Alauda arvensis*), and the grassy landscape of the big picture also fits this hypothesis.

From [Animal Diversity Web](http://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Alauda_arvensis/) (an extremely reliable and well-referenced source of animal information), a short description of the skylark's famous and distinctive flight display:

> Male skylarks sing throughout the day, starting in the dawn hours. The song is mostly heard February through July, but a more faint song can be heard throughout the rest of the year. They usually begin their song after flying into the air 10-20 m. They then progress to flying 50-100 m up, then slowly spiral down with periods of hovering in the air. This can proceed for 10-15 minutes.

[image]

I don't know of any other bird which displays the same flight pattern as the skylark.

And they tend to be found in grasslands, which fits with the image you provided:

> Skylarks live in areas of open country. They are generally found living in extensive croplands, marshes, or meadows. They prefer to live among cereal grasses or low green herbage.

Comment: I haven't seen the new season yet, but to my knowledge, there is no example of a Skylark in-universe. It's doubtful that they even exist. Considering that the entire setting oozes magic out of it's pores and flying can be pretty trivial, it could be any number of creatures, with the likely culprit being another pony. Hilariously enough, there *is* a pony named [Skylark](http://mylittlewiki.org/wiki/Skylark) from the original MLP universe. But Skylark doesn't seem to exist in Friendship is Magic (yet).

Answer (score 0):

It's Thorax, who decided to abandon his hive and then later made an appearance in S6 Ep16 'The Times They Are A Changeling'.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence of this?